# In a crawl space how do i secure electric cables?

Tags: crawlspace

In a crawl space, can I staple the electric 12/2 cable to the floor joist?

Comment: Do you mean along the side of floor joists halfway up, or do you mean  hopping from bottom to bottom creating a mouse jungle gym?

Comment: Yes, creating a mouse jungle gym.  Running the 12/2 cable perpendicular to the joists.

Answer (score 1):

### Current Code has a certain rule for running non metallic and simlar cables in craw spaces.

> **334.15(C) 2017 NEC** Cables not smaller than **#6/2** or **#8/3** can be directly stabled to the lower edges. Smaller cables can be run through bored holes **or running boards**.

The running board solution is usually the easiest. The running board should be at least the height of the cable.

Answer (score 0):

In my jurisdiction, at least, I have received confirmation that this is acceptable.